# How to tell Compass what environment this is?

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, sass, compass-sass

In my Compass project I have a `config.rb` with the setting `environment = :development`.

How do I tell Compass that, when it is run on the server (for example `compass compile`), the environment should be `production`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the Docs](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/production-css/)

Option A: Use the compass production defaults.

```
compass compile -e production --force
```

Note: This only changes the compass defaults, options you've specified explicitly in your configuration will not be changed.

Option B: Override your configuration file settings on the command line

```
compass compile --output-style compressed --force
```

Option C: Create a separate configuration file for production

```
cp config.rb prod_config.rb
```

..edit prod_config.rb to suit  your needs..

```
compass compile -c prod_config.rb --force
```

Comment: I really need to look harder before I ask for help. I did `compass --help` and also checked the online docs, but rushed here too early. Thanks!